# No matching function for call with 6 arguments when it only needs 2

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm having a problem testing my class because one of the test cases gives me an array with 6 values and my functions seem to not catch it. How can I modify them so they work?
Test case:

```
case 2:{
  BiStack<long> b{1,2,3,4,5,6};
  cout << b.capacity() << endl;
  cout << b.size() << endl;
  cout << b.max() << endl;
  break;
```

and these are my functions in my header file:

```
BiStack() = default;
BiStack(size_t init, size_t max);
BiStack(initializer_list<ElementT>, size_t max);
```

it gives me this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'BiStack<long int>::BiStack(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
     BiStack<long> b{1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

I don't know if this is enough info but I appreciate the help!

Comment: The constructor with initializer list needs 2 arguments. You didn't specify the value for 'max' argument. Try BiStack<long> b{{1,2,3,4,5,6}, 6};

Comment: and if the test case can't be modified, what can I change on the other end?

Comment: You need to have a  BitStack constructor with single argument: BiStack(initializer_list<ElementT>) if you want to do BiStack<long> b{1,2,3,4,5,6};

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use this constructor:

```
BiStack(initializer_list<ElementT>, size_t max);
```

So, use this initialization:

```
BiStack<long> b{{1,2,3,4,5}, 6};
```

If the test case can't be modified, you can add one more constructor `BiStack`:

```
BiStack(initializer_list<ElementT>); // last element is 'max'
```

Answer (score 0):

`BiStack(initializer_list<ElementT>, size_t max);`

This won't match to `BiStack<long> b{1,2,3,4,5,6};` since there is no way to match second parameter `max`. All six elements are considered as part of initializer list. You can get the size from the list itself like this, i.e. without second parameter in constructor:

```
BiStack(initializer_list<ElementT> lst) {
    size_t max = lst.size();
}
```

Or if the `max` can be different than the list size then you can separate the second parameter with an additional `{}` like this:

```
BiStack<long> b{{1,2,3,4,5,6}, 100};
```

Answer (score 0):

following init-list:

```
BiStack<long> b{1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

means your constructor is taking 6 parameters, but you defined it

```
BiStack(initializer_list<ElementT>, size_t max);
```

so you are missing the **size_t**  argument